# How to raise a numpy array to a power? (corresponding to repeated matrix multiplications, not elementwise)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to raise a 2-dimensional numpy `array`, let's call it `A`, to the power of some number `n`, but I have thus far failed to find the function or operator to do that.

I'm aware that I could cast it to the `matrix` type and use the fact that then (similar to what would be the behaviour in Matlab), `A**n` does just what I want, (for `array` the same  expression means elementwise exponentiation). Casting to `matrix` and back seems like a rather ugly workaround though.

Surely there must be a good way to perform that calculation while keeping the format to `array`?

Comment: While its possible as Joe Kingston pointed out, note that arrays and matrices are fundamentally different.  An `array` is a numerical collection of elements in multi-dimensions, where a `matrix` is an abstract object (represented by an 2-d array)-- the same difference as between a vector and a 1-d array.  (It makes sense for an inventory of fruit to be a array of [1,2,3] representing 1 apple, 2 oranges, 3 bananas but no sense for an vector -- apples can't add/multiple/transform into oranges).  Thus arrays have element-by-element operations and matrices have matrix multiplications, det(), etc.

Comment: If you like Joe's answer, you should check it as "accepted", to give credit to Joe and to let others know this question is dealt with.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe you want [`numpy.linalg.matrix_power`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html)

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
y = np.matrix(x)

a = y**3
b = np.linalg.matrix_power(x, 3)

print a
print b
assert np.all(a==b)
```

This yields:

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
matrix([[ 180,  234,  288],
        [ 558,  720,  882],
        [ 936, 1206, 1476]])

In [20]: b
Out[20]: 
array([[ 180,  234,  288],
       [ 558,  720,  882],
       [ 936, 1206, 1476]])
```

Comment: I feel somewhat sheepish for not having thought to look explicitly in the `linalg` module, but particular thanks for pointing out that that's the place as well. Nice quick example; very illustrative.

Answer (score -1):

The opencv function cvPow seems to be about 3-4 times faster on my computer when raising to a rational number. 
Here is a sample function (you need to have the pyopencv module installed):

```
import pyopencv as pycv
import numpy
def pycv_power(arr, exponent):
    """Raise the elements of a floating point matrix to a power. 
    It is 3-4 times faster than numpy's built-in power function/operator."""
    if arr.dtype not in [numpy.float32, numpy.float64]:
        arr = arr.astype('f')
    res = numpy.empty_like(arr)
    if arr.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'] == False:
        arr = numpy.ascontiguousarray(arr)        
    pycv.pow(pycv.asMat(arr), float(exponent), pycv.asMat(res))
    return res
```

Comment: the pow function raises each value on the matrix by power n which is different from matrix power which raises the matrix by power n (multiply the matrix by itself n times)