# In Python, how can I raise a square matrix represented as a numpy.ndarray to non-integer powers?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, exponent

Assume I have a square matrix which can be raised to the -1/2 power. 
I want to raise the square matrix represented as a `numpy.ndarray` to -1/2.

Note I want to raise the matrix to a non-integer power.  I do not want raise each element of the matrix to a non-integer power.

I know I can raise a matrix to an integer power using `numpy.linalg.matrix_power` as described in [How to raise a numpy array to a power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018552/how-to-raise-a-numpy-array-to-a-power-corresponding-to-repeated-matrix-multipl)

How can I raise a `numpy.ndarray` to non-integer powers?

Comment: If you mean a matrix M where `numpy.allclose(original_matrix, numpy.linalg.inv(M.dot(M)))` holds, which such M do you want? If you want the elementwise inverse square root, that's just `original_matrix**-0.5`.

Comment: @user2357112 In my case M is a covariance. I want to raise the matrix (not each element) to the -1/2 power.

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee that a general n x n matrix can be raised to a given non-integer power. This operation is well-defined for positive integer powers, and using Maclaurin series you can then define a matrix exponential function for approximating other functions of matrices.

However, to be able to raise a matrix to an arbitrary power, you must also have a coherent definition of a matrix logarithm, which is only well-defined for invertible matrices and involves some subtlety about uniqueness and the field of elements over which it is defined.

This is covered reasonably well at [this math.stackexchange.com answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364653/26927).

So in general, this is not a well-defined operation on arbitrary n x n matrices, and thus it wouldn't make sense as a generically available function on `ndarray`.

It's like asking for a function called "`inverse`" that calculates an inverse (not a psuedo-inverse or any approximation, but the "actual" inverse) for arbitrary 2D arrays. Such a function can't exist in general, since there are non-invertible 2D arrays.

It's somewhat of a parochial API decision as to whether there is some function that purports to compute it and merely throws an exception if it can detect an invalid input argument, such as `numpy.linalg.inv`, versus just not providing that functionality and expecting the user to write their own function to do it and to handle checking argument validity, raising exceptions, or whatever failure-case behavior is required.

`inv` is ubiquitous enough to warrant this effort, whereas out-of-the-box arbitrary powers are not.

Answer (score 4):

SciPy has [`scipy.linalg.sqrtm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.sqrtm.html), which computes a matrix square root. It's not clear whether it attempts to compute any particular square root - for example, the principal square root - but if the input has square roots, `sqrtm` will compute one. Thus, you can do

```
invsqrt = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(scipy.linalg.inv(input_matrix))
```

though you'll likely want to do some error-handling.