# How to raise a numpy.matrix to non-integer power?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

The `**` operator for `numpy.matrix` does not support non-integer power:

```
>>> m
 matrix([[ 1. ,  0. ],
    [ 0.5,  0.5]])

>>> m ** 2.5
TypeError: exponent must be an integer
```

What I want is

```
octave:14> [1 0; .5 .5] ^ 2.5
ans =

   1.00000   0.00000
   0.82322   0.17678
```

Can I do this with `numpy` or `scipy`?

#### Note:

this is NOT an element-wise operation. It is an matrix (in linear algebra) raised to some power, as talked in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16739/arbitrary-non-integer-power-of-a-matrix).

Comment: it should work with an array. Personally, I always use arrays. Leads to sometimes a bit clumsy code but I do not have to distinguish between matrix and array objects.

Comment: The question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406681/in-python-how-can-i-raise-a-square-matrix-represented-as-a-numpy-ndarray-to-non, but the answers don't overlap much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power.html#scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power):

```
>>> m
matrix([[ 1. ,  0. ],
        [ 0.5,  0.5]])
>>> scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power(m, 2.5)
array([[ 1.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 0.8232233,  0.1767767]])
```

Comment: Great! That's just what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364613/can-you-raise-a-matrix-to-a-non-integer-number) you can see that the power of a matrix can be rewritten as: [image].

This code, making use of scipy.linalg, gives as a result the same as Octave:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import logm, expm

M = np.matrix([[ 1. ,  0. ],[ 0.5,  0.5]])
x = 2.5
A = logm(M)*x
P = expm(A)
```

This is the output for P:

```
Out[19]: 
array([[ 1.       , -0.       ],
   [ 0.8232233,  0.1767767]])
```