# Python: Raise square matrix to negative half power

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am trying to compute the matrix B which has the following equation: 
`B = A^2`.

Assume that A is a matrix:

```
array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

When I take the negative half power of this matrix in Matlab `(A^-0.5)`. I get the following result:

ans =

```
   0.1031 - 1.2474i   0.1502 + 0.5706i

   0.2253 + 0.8559i   0.3284 - 0.3915i
```

However, in Python using the code `(A**-0.5)` I get different results

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.57735027,  0.5       ]]).
```

My question is how can I use Python to replicate the Matlab output. I have tried numpy function numpy.linalg.matrix_power(M, n), but this fails as it only takes integers as a second argument, whereas I need a float. Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to raise a numpy.matrix to non-integer power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409876/how-to-raise-a-numpy-matrix-to-non-integer-power)

Comment: It's probably important to note that standard operations on `numpy` matrices are "element wise" (The `.*`, `.^`, etc.) operators in MatLab. For matrix operations you use `@` for matrix multiplication and need `scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power` for matrix exponentiation.

Answer (score 10):

`scipy.linalg` supports fractional matrix powers:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import fractional_matrix_power

A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

fractional_matrix_power(A, -0.5)

# array([[ 0.10306396-1.24742804j,  0.15020820+0.5706074j ],
#        [ 0.22531231+0.8559111j ,  0.32837626-0.39151694j]])
```

Comment: However this does not work over a batch of matrices (_,N,N)