# How to record all eigenvalues of a matrix in form of a diagonal matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, svd

I used svd of a matrix `A` of size 64*64 in Python as follows.

```
U,D,V=svd(A)
```

Now, `D` is an array of all eigenvalues of `A`. How to rewrite all values in `D` as a diagonal matrix? For example, if `D=[d1,d2,d3,d4]`, how to have

```
D_new=[[d1,0,0,0],[0,d2,0,0],[0,0,0,d3],[0,0,0,d4]]?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a diagonal matrix with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139494/how-can-i-create-a-diagonal-matrix-with-numpy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using numpy :**

```
import numpy as np 
d = [d1,d2,d3]
diagonal = np.diag(d)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask how to compute the `diagonal^(-1/2)` in Python?

Comment: @quasAliki Ask new questions in separate posts, not in comments. But if you do some simple searching, you'll find your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018552/how-to-raise-a-numpy-array-to-a-power-corresponding-to-repeated-matrix-multipl)

Comment: @Woodford Well, this seems does not work for (-1/2).

Comment: yes you can , do the following : `diagonal**(-1/2)` . But, it wouldn't work because you will have 1/0 which would be calculated as `inf` (infinity)

Comment: but , these is a solution : is `D = np.array(d)` then `D**(-1/2) ` then `diagonal = np.diag(D)`

Answer (score 1):

create an empty vector of zero based on the length of your eigenvalues, then assign the position as you iterate over the list, appending to create a diagonal matrix

```
d=['d1','d2','d3','d4']
dnew=[]

for i,x in enumerate(d):
    vec=[0 for x in d]
    vec[i]=d[i]
    dnew.append(vec)

for x in dnew:
    print(x)  


['d1', 0, 0, 0]
[0, 'd2', 0, 0]
[0, 0, 'd3', 0]
[0, 0, 0, 'd4']
```